# List all database fields in use within my Crystal Reports programmatically

Tags: database, sdk, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

If I open up a Crystal Report (v. XI) manually, I can see within the Field Explorer which Database fields are in use (they're checked off).  How can I find this out programmatically?  I tried cycling through the fields found in the Table object (see code below) using the API, but I then get a list of *all* database fields within the tables in question, even if they are not used within my report!

```
For Each t As Table In rptDoc.Database.Tables
            For Each fld As DatabaseFieldDefinition In t.Fields
                debug.print(fld.name)
            Next
        Next
```

I also tried the following code, but still didn't get all the fields I was expecting to see:

```
For Each RO As ReportObject In rptDoc.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects
        If RO.Kind = ReportObjectKind.FieldObject Then
            fo = DirectCast(RO, FieldObject)
            Debug.Print(fo.DataSource.Name.ToString)
        End If
    Next
```

HELP!!!

Comment: I decided to search through the Crystal Report using the DataDefinition and ReportDefinition classes and scan through each formula, running total, Group, etc. and inspect each text formula withing these objects in order to dissect which database fields are utilitzed (very tedious).  However, I can't seem to find the database fields that are used within CrossTab objects or the Suppress Formulas for, say, lines and boxes.  Very frustrating! Why couldn't Crystal get the "UseCount" to work properly!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there :)

Use the `UseCount` property which represent the number of times the field is in use on the report.

```
For Each t As Table In rptDoc.Database.Tables
    For Each fld As DatabaseFieldDefinition In t.Fields
        If fld.UseCount > 0 Then
            Debug.Print(fld.Name)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

or

```
For Each RO As ReportObject In rptDoc.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects
    If RO.Kind = ReportObjectKind.FieldObject Then
        Dim fo As FieldObject = DirectCast(RO, FieldObject)

        If fo.DataSource.UseCount > 0 Then
            Debug.Print(fo.DataSource.Name.ToString)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Nice try, but UseCount is obsolete.  It doesn't even work (I get UseCount = 1 even if the field is not used in the report)

Comment: Sorry about that you are [absolutely right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225645%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Nevertheless it does work in some versions. I tried it in [CR Runtime 13.0.9](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) and it's OK.

Comment: Thanks @David , the UseCount worked perfectly for me.